# Extract /var/mobile/containers/data/application from an IPhone or backup

Tags: iphone, ios, backup

I need to extract my Snapchat data which is located in a folder in /var/mobile/containers/data/application/(snapchat).

The problem is it doesn't seem any of the backup browsers offer this?

I also tried sideloading iFile but I can't access it from there, and my phone is not Jailbroken and can't be(10.2.1).

Does anyone know how  I can get this? It's very important to me.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps can choose to not include data in their container from an iTunes backup, so the folder won't appear in a backup. Snapchat do this, which means the container isn't backed up when you do an iTunes backup and the data inside won't be able to be accessed.

You can't access other app's containers without jailbreaking. Unfortunately, this means that data isn't accessible.

Comment: Ah that's a shame to hear, thanks anyways though for telling me that